# Windows 7/8 - Kiosk - Isolation

Tags: windows, google-chrome, java, kiosk

I've built a custom kiosk application in .Net that has shortcuts to specific URL's in Chrome, Volume Control, etc.. It's working great and we are using a user GPO "Custom User Interface" to replace explorer.exe with the application.

However, this does not prevent things like Norton Security, Java Updates, etc.. to open and interrupt the user experience.

I've tried GPO's like "allow only these programs" and Software Restriction Policies to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My goal is to only allow the bare minimum services, Chrome, Java, and Sndvol.exe to run, while everything is suppressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1, a Kiosk mode was introduced. It allows for one single App to run for that user, and hides the desktop and Metro interface.

To set it up, you need an account with Administrative Permissions. Install the application, then go to your PC Settings (swipe from the right, or hover the lower right corner of the screen). Go to the User Accounts section, and add a new user. For type, choose Limited, then choose the Kiosk option. It'll ask for the application to run, and let you save your preferences.

Whenever this new user logs in, they get the one application, and that's it.

Comment: I need this to work in both Windows 7 & 8, and this would be across 500+ computers. That sounds like what I'm looking for, similar to "Guide Access" on an iPad, but wouldnt work in an enterprise.

Comment: You should edit your question to mention these requirements

Comment: There are established kiosk solutions for Windows 7.